# Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to move from viewcontroller to viewcontroller without segue so I tried this code :

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewsDetailsVCID") as! NewsViewController
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But I am getting this error:

> 'Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit'

Comment: There's probably a pop-up icon in XCode next to the error that will perform the necessary fix for you if you click 'Fix'.

Comment: So do what it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said, do what it says.
Instead of:

```
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

adding self gets:

```
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing this code inside of a closure, so you need to use `self.` to be explicit about capturing.  Just change:

`present(vc, animated: true, completed: nil)`

to

`self.present(vc, animated: true, completed: nil)`